# How to install cyanogenmod on LG P690 optimus net: how to know which ROM?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod

I would like to install an android 4.x ROM on my Optimus Net (P690) Android 2.3.4.

When I go to the CyanogenMod downloads page at http://get.cm I see various phones but not mine. However [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd__3LDsB40) shows that such an installation is possible. Alas this page does not show where to get the ROM image from.

Could anyone suggest where to get it from?

Comment: A good source starting your ROM search is: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). The answer (community wiki) of this question mentions a lot of good ressources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd__3LDsB40) refers to an [XDA page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1651974) as shown below:
[image]
That XDA page gives further details about the CM9 ROM, GApps and instructions.

Your LG P690's hardware seems to be a close match to my LG P500. So, if you are not satisfied with the ROM mentioned, you can give a shot with LGP500's ROM - the chances of getting it working in your P690 is good. Please search this site for details on knowing from where to download ROM for P500.